# How to blur google map with css

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I'm making a semi-transparent panel to overlay on my map, and I thought blurring the map underneath it would be a neat effect. I tried using CSS filters, namely `filter: blur(5px);`, however this only blurred the contents of the panel, not the map beneath it.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this effect?

(Picture of simple div panel with no blurring, yet)

[image: Not blurred]

Comment: Wait a few years then you can use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter

Comment: Why the downvote though?

Comment: Probably cause you haven't shown what you tried as required with this: [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. put the map in a `.wrapper` div
2. apply the filter to that div
3. then add the overlay background to a [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) of that div.

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<!-- initilize map -->
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {
        lat: 40.674,
        lng: -73.945
      },
      zoom: 12,
    })
  }
</script>



<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="map" style='width: 100%; height: 100%;'></div>
</div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDHu4QBgWONqtdOWVLTW5XZ51B1eOU6SWw&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

I have two notes on this:

1. This [won't work on IE](http://caniuse.com/css-filters/embed)
2. your design idea breaks Google maps terms and conditions as you are
   hiding the google logo. If you must go through with this, be sure to
   read the terms and conditions really well

Comment: Thanks, this looks great! It would be even better if it could blur only the portion of the map below the overlay, which won't cover the entire map.

Comment: For those coming from Google, you can use `backdrop-filter: blur(5px);` in your overlay panel css. Although as 2019 still doesn't work in all browsers, but works great in Chrome, Edge, Safari... and you can always have a fallback.